# Iterator interface and method

Tags: java, collections

```
ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
Iterator itr = al.iterator(); 
while (itr.hasNext())
{  
    Student st = (Student) itr.next();
    System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+""+st.age);                                                  
}
```

Assume Student class having three data members rollno,name and age.
So,my question is why we downcast in the statement Student st=(Student)itr.next(); 
But if we make an ArrayList having **String** as types of data members,then there is no need to downcast it using iterator again.
Please help to clear my doubt.

Comment: IIRC `al.iterator()` would return a `Iterator<Student>` so there's no need for the cast. It's only needed because you removed the generics from `Iterator itr`. Btw, the same would be true for `ArrayList<String>`, if you experience different results you most likely have different code (e.g. you're using `Iterator<String>` in that case).

Comment: You could just change `Iterator itr` to `Iterator<Student> itr`.

Comment: I believe you still have to cast : `String st = (String)itr.next();` otherwise it won't compile. How did you assume that you don't need to cast if the type of object in the list is String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using a raw `Iterator`.

Parametrize your `Iterator` as such: `Iterator<Student> itr=al.iterator();`

Then you won't have to explicitly cast the `next` invocation (returning `Object` when raw) to `Student`.

You can also spare yourself the clutter if you're just iterating and printing, and use fast enumeration instead:

```
for (Student s: al) {
    // print stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) can take advantage of generics, so you can have an `Iterator<Student>` that will return a `Student` instance when invoking [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--).

Actually [`al.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--) is already returning an `Iterator<Student>`, you're just erasing its generics by assigning it to a raw `Iterator`.

Check out this related question: [Iterator vs Iterator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573031/851811).